# bibliotecas C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, biblioteca, windows-10

meu problema é o seguinte: minha atividade da faculdade é criar um programa em que o usuário possa deslocar o cursor da tela para onde ele quiser, utilizando coordenadas, e também o usuário pode mudar a cor do texto e o fundo do texto. Esse programa precisa ser escrito em C++. eu sei que da pra usar a biblioteca "windows.h" para isso, mas o meu professor disse que não pode usar nenhuma biblioteca do C, tem que ser do C++, ou seja, não pode usar nenhuma biblioteca com ".h" e também não poderei usar o comando "system(""color x)", usando o cmd do Windows. eu queria saber se tem uma biblioteca própria do C++ para isso, ou outro método que vocês me aconselharem. meu sistema é o Windows 10, e estou usando o VISUAL STUDIO 2017.

Comment: Talvez está te ajude `#include <QtGui>`, leia mais [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt) e [aqui](http://www.qtsoftware.de/).

Answer (score 1):

O conceito de tela não existe em C ou C++. Esta abstração costuma ser fornecida pelo sistema operacional ou por terceiros.

Perceba que nomear um header com `.h` não o torna código C. Headers de usuário em C++ também são habitualmente nomeados com `.h` e incluídos com `#include "meu_header.h"`.

Para ilustrar este conceito, você pode salvar seu header sem o `.h` e o incluir com `#include "meu_header"`. Se quiser ir além e usar `< >`, como em `#include <meu_header>`, basta copiar o arquivo para algum dos diretórios padrões de headers usados pelo compilador (no meu MacOS, por exemplo /usr/local/include). Nada disso tornará seu código nem mais ou nem menos C++.

O header `windows.h` é parte integrante da API do Windows (`WinAPI`). A `WinAPI` possui várias versões dependendo da plataforma, por exemplo `Win16`, `Win32` e `Win64`. A WinAPI visa ser utilizada por códigos tipicamente em idioma C. Outras APIs foram desenvolvidas encapsulando a `WinAPI` no intuito de facilitar seu uso, ex. `MFC`, `ATL`, `WTL`. Por exemplo, a `MFC` foi desenvolvida com o conceito de orientação a objetos para uso típico em C++. Em última instância, a maioria dos frameworks para Windows utilizarão a `WinAPI`, incluindo `.NET` e `Java`. Portanto, se for utilizar as funcionalidades GUI do Windows, seu código provavelmente estará dependendo da `WinAPI`, mesmo que de forma não aparente.

Se o objetivo é desenvolver uma aplicação GUI utilizando bibliotecas de terceiros, há opções como `Qt` e `wxWidgets`.

Enfim, se o que deseja é emular uma tela em modo texto (estilo `ncurses`) usando apenas C++ e a STL, então acredito que o caminho é valer-se de caracteres ASCII especiais e imprimir seguidamente a saída de texto de forma sobreposta.